# How to change default date color and Sunday column color?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I am customizing the color of default date picker. I have changed almost all color but **unable to change date color and Sunday column**. Please help me change the date and Sunday color.

- My style

  ```
      <style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
      <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorOrange</item>
      <item name="android:background">@color/colorGreyDark</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
      <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>
      </style>
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:headerBackground is property you are looking for. 
Relevant link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:headerBackground

Comment: Thank you, It is working for changing the date color. But about to change the All Sunday columns colors?